# Separating a list of names into : "FirstName {TAB} Lastname" pairs

Tags: text, entity, extract, names

Is there a specific library, algorithm or technique (besides using Regular expressions)
to use if you want to convert/translate the following lines.

```
"Acme Corporation Inc., John, Doe, F."
"Smith, Allen, Smith,Susan"
"Marshall, J., L., Johnson, H., Caruso, D., Jones, J."
"Stein, Harry, Joan, and Mike"
```

These lines should be converted into text containing:

```
Acme {TAB} Corporation
Doe {TAB} John
Smith {TAB} Allen
Smith {TAB} Susan
Marshall {TAB} J.
Johnson {TAB} H.
Caruso {TAB} D.
Jones {TAB} J.
Stein {TAB} Harry
Stein {TAB} Joan
Stein {TAB} Mike
```

The original text contains only proper names and middle initials (D. or J.) except for
an occasional "and" separating siblings with the same last name as in the last line
of original text above.

Also, is this considered to be "Named Entity Recognition" or is there some other technical
name for this process?

Ideally, i would like code or algorithms in a language like Ruby/Python/Perl/PHP that could
make this translation.

Any Ideas?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't this interpret `John, Doe, F.` as `John Doe` and `John F.`? Why wouldn't `Marshall, J., L., ` be interpreted as `Marshall J.` and `Marshall L.`? My instincts say that parsing this is enormously non-trivial without a large amount of heuristics.

Answer (score 0):

This works, almost:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tok = undef;
my @pairs = ();
my $looking_for = 'surname';

sub parse_line_to_words($){
    my $l = shift;
    my @words;
    my $word = '';
    my $start = 1;

    # remove trailing newlines
    chomp $l;
    if(index($l, '"', -1) != -1){
            # remove trailing quotation mark.
            chop $l;
    }
    foreach my $c (split//,$l){
            if($c eq '"'){
                    if($#words == -1){
                            # skip leading quotation marks
                            next;
                    }
            }

            if($c eq ','){
                    push(@words, $word);
                    $word = '';
                    $start = 1;
            } else{
                    if($start && $c eq ' '){
                            next;
                    } else{
                            $start = 0;
                    }
                    $word .= $c;
            }
    }
    if($word ne ''){
            push(@words, $word);
    }
    return @words;
}
sub peek_and(@){
    foreach my $word (@_){
            return 1 if $word eq 'and'
    }
    return 0;
}
sub split_and(@){
    my @copy;
    foreach my $word (@_){
            if(index($word, 'and ', 0) != -1){
                    my $i = index($word, 'and ', 0) + 4;
                    push(@copy, substr($word, 0, $i - 1));
                    push(@copy, substr($word, $i));
            } else{
                    push(@copy, $word);
            }
    }
    return @copy;
}
sub count_spaces($){
    my $w = shift;
    my $s=0;
    for(my $p = index($w, ' ', 0); $p != -1; $p=index($w, ' ', $p+1), $s++) {}
    return $s;
}
sub found($$$){
    my $pairs = shift;
    push(@{$pairs}, {'surname' => shift, 'firstname' => shift});
}
while(<>){
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    my @words = parse_line_to_words($line);
    @words = split_and(@words);
    my $line_has_and = peek_and(@words);
    foreach my $word (@words){
            my $spaces = count_spaces($word);

            if($looking_for eq 'surname'){
                    if(index($word, '.', -1) != -1 && $spaces == 0){
                            # looks like an initial to me, skip it
                    } else{
                            if($spaces > 0){
                                    # multi-word token; must be corporation name
                                    my($f, $l) = split(/ /, $word);
                                    found(\@pairs, $f, $l);
                            } else{
                                    $tok = $word;
                                    $looking_for = 'firstname';
                            }
                    }
            } elsif ($looking_for eq 'firstname'){
                    if($line_has_and){
                            # lastname, first1, ..., firstn and firstn+1
                            if($word ne 'and'){
                                    found(\@pairs, $tok, $word);
                            }
                    } else{
                            # lastname, f. or lastname, firstname
                            found(\@pairs, $tok, $word);
                            $looking_for = 'surname';
                    }
            }
    }
    $looking_for = 'surname'; # reset for new line
}

foreach my $p (@pairs){
    printf("%s\t%s\n", $p->{'surname'}, $p->{'firstname'});
}
```

## Actual output for given sample input

```
Acme    Corporation
John    Doe
Smith   Allen
Smith   Susan
Marshall        J.
Johnson H.
Caruso  D.
Jones   J.
Stein   Harry
Stein   Joan
Stein   Mike
```

## Discussion

I employed the following heuristics:

- Leading and trailing quotation marks on a line should be ignored.
- Each line can be tokenized into words as a series of comma-delimited values.
- If a word begins with space characters then those characters should be ignored.
- The first word of any pair of words is a surname, the second a first name (except special cases).
- If a word on a line begins with 'and ' the entire line should be treated specially where the first word is a surname and the rest are corresponding first names.
- If a surname has more than 0 spaces then it is the name of a corporation
- A corporation name is always two space-delimited words which should be treated as surname and firstname respectively.
- Non-corporation names do not contain spaces.

In the end I used "regular expressions" only to split corporation names on space; this could be trivially replaced with a non-regex version.

Even with all of this I still get "John Doe" wrong, because its names are reversed in the input. I couldn't devise a reliable way to detect this.